# Is there any way to make a command both text-based and slash-based in Pycord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I've made a music bot in Pycord, and I want to make the commands both slash and text-based. I've implemented slash commands using `discord.Bot` in a `cog` and used the `slash_command` decorator.

All the code of the music bot can be seen [here](https://github.com/Team-AxC/Bots-AxC/tree/main/AxC%20777%20Music/slash) (the `main_slash.py` file contains the `cog`)

I have some hint that `discord.ext.commands.Bot` can be used, but well, to say the least, I am bewildered and perplexed in this context on using this class in my code.

I have tried these things:-

1. Using `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, but this ended up in failure (as mentioned before).
2. (current method, but inefficient I guess) Running two instances of the bot parallelly, with one implementing slash commands, while the other implementing text-based commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridges exist on Pycord now and you can just do:

```py
@bot.bridge_command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Hello!")
```

and it'll be both a text-based and slash-based command.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a seperate async function and then the slash command an prefixed command call that separate async function.

`discord.ext.commands.Bot` supports slash commands and prefix commands please read the docs

Comment: I got it, but as I mentioned I am having a hard time making a command _both_ slash-based and text-based using just a _single_ decorator and not cluttering up the code with the same function/method being executed by two different commands, with one using the `slash_command` decorator, while the other using the `commands.command` decorator. I need some help with this. I am bad at comprehending API references and documentation, so if possible, please help me out _just a little bit_ more on this one.

Comment: you can manually register slash command and prefixed commands instead of using the decorator

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope this works well and ends well!